# What code should i add to print out "seat already taken" if user input seats that are taken already or input the same seat?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make seat reservation or assignment using one dimensional array. A user input choose 2 sections whether economy class or first class but i dont wanna go that far since i dont understand yet the algorithm. Lets assume user inputs first class and choose seats from seat 1, the user input must be saved in the array. If user inputs the same seat again, it must print out seat already taken. how can i work printing out 'seat already taken' if user inputs seats that are taken or inputs the same seat?

```
int arr[] = new int[10];


    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println ("(1)First Class \n(2)Economy Class");
        int section = input.nextInt();

        if(section == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Welcome to First Class");
            System.out.println ("Choose Seat from 1-2");
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();

            if(arr[i] == 1)
            {
                            arr[0]=1;
                System.out.println ("Seat #1");
            }
            else if(arr[i] == 2)
            {
                arr[1]=2;
                System.out.println ("Seat #2");
            }
            else if(arr[i] == arr[0] || arr[i]==arr[1])
            {
                System.out.println ("Seat already taken");
            }

        }
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: how can i work printing out 'seat already taken' if user inputs seats that are taken or inputs the same seat? @Turing85

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the actual question.

Comment: @turing85 can you help me make this code possible?

Comment: why are yoi setting arr(1) and arr(2) over and ocer again instead of arr(i)?

Comment: Your description of the problem and the code don't match up at all.

Comment: @Antoniossss i wanna set user input to the specific array because if ever they input the same seat again, ill call it to identify if that array is available or not. Tbh, i dont understand the algo.

Comment: @ShashwatKhanna yea i know. I cant get the logic in making the program. Can you help me make it possible?

Comment: again, you got 10 seats or passengers and you are setting only 0 and 1 instead of all 10

Comment: @Antioniosssss should i change it to arr[i] = arr[0] to move the user input to the specific arrayindex?

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand the relation between the code you've provided and the problem you're trying to solve.

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to see if the array already contains an element which is input by a user. For that, you could do something like this

```
int a[] = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    boolean seatTaken = false;
    int seat = input.nextInt();
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[j]==seat){
            seatTaken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(seatTaken){
        System.out.println("The Seat has already been taken");
        i = i - 1;
    }else{
       a[i] = seat;
    }
}
```

Of course, this could be made a lot more efficient by using a HashSet which has a constant lookup time